# How to remove all data from DynamoDB without for loop?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Suppose i have 100 data in DynamoDB then to remove all data i have to execute for loop .So is there any way to remove all data without for loop ?

```
let dynamoDbObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()

for var key in 0 ..<100 {

    let itemToDelete: CategoriesDB = CategoriesDB()
    itemToDelete._index = key

    dynamoDbObjectMapper.remove(itemToDelete, completionHandler:              
    {(error: Error?) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print(" Amazon DynamoDB Save Error: \(error)")
            return
        }
        print("A Category was deleted.")
    })
}
```

Comment: You want to delete the data, but want to keep the table?

Comment: Yes, i don't want to delete table just remove all data from it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all the data in a DynamoDB table, it is better to just delete the table and create it again as that wouldn't cost Write Capacity Units.

Comment: If the table has been created by CloudFormation this may not be an option. CloudFormation may set up security groups, VPCs, allow lists, etc. and you may wish to keep these concerns out of application code.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the swift SDK for a moment, DynamoDB has the DeleteItem method to remove a single item from a table, but it also has a batch method.

[Quote](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.DeleteData.html)

> In addition to DeleteItem, Amazon DynamoDB supports a BatchWriteItem
>   action for deleting multiple items at the same time.

The problem is, I can't see a way to access [BatchWriteItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) through the [swift SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-ios-dynamodb-objectmapper.html). Even if you could use BatchWriteItem, it can only take 25 items at a time, so you would still end up having to write a loop.

Sorry its not a more complete answer, but thought this might be useful. As far as I know there isn't a simple (single) method for doing this.